# Unexpected Token * Koa.js

Tags: node.js, koa

I'm getting a harmony error when trying to run Koa.

Here is the error after I ran my mocha tests, I get this error at the end:

```
MacBook-Pro$ mocha test
...projects/search-api/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:179
function *respond(next) {
         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

[image]

Here's my **server.js**

```
'use strict';

var supertestKoa = require('supertest-koa-agent');

var app = module.exports = require('koa')(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

supertestKoa(app);

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Koa app is listening on port' + port);
});
```

Let me know if you need anything else from me to help troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's failing on the generator `function*` syntax. Here are a few options to get around this:

- If you're using node 0.11 or higher, you'll need to enable es6 generators by running with harmony. Typically I do something like this: `node --harmony path/to/mocha`.
- Alternatively, you can upgrade to io.js, which supports generators and a few other es6 goodies without needing a runtime flag.
- One other possibility is running the tests using the babel transpiler. The [babel website](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/) has detailed instructions how to do that (look for "mocha" on that page). This is probably your best bet if you're still on node 0.10 or lower, which have zero generator support.

Comment: You *need* to use 0.11 or above in node.js for generators to work.

Comment: Transpilers should allow generators to run on older engines (see my last bullet).

Comment: You can always do everything in programming, but the question is what is the most advisable for the user!

Comment: I'm trying to use babel.  So I've tried to setup babel in my gulp file as well as here's an example of my test script in my package.json: "test": "mocha node_modules/.bin/mocha --harmony test --compilers js:babel/register"...does that seem right?

Comment: What about using the `node` command directly instead of `mocha` like this: `node --harmony node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel/register`?

Comment: eh?  come again?  I want this stuff done as much as possible via gulp so devs who pull this down have to do minimal setup, and npm install should take care of most the stuff...there will be some things they'll need to still install global but trying to keep that to a minimum for their side...

Comment: I'm past the error now, I had to install babel globally, tried to keep it in devDependencies and that wasn't enough apparently because it was scoped to my node_modules folder that sits in the root of my project.

Comment: I'm using gulp to automate those commands is why I don't type it directly every time.... So in my gulpfile at the top I have  require('babel/register'); and it still doesn't work.

Comment: so I'm not even using a script in my  package.json, I am using all tasks in gulp to run my tests, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `function *` in application.js not your node file. `function *` is a generator function in ES6 (ES2015) http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3agenerators. This is the next version of javascript that not all version of browsers/node.js support yet.

There are a couple options here you can transpile that file back to ES5 so that browsers/node.js can understand it. You can also use something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code back to ES5. You can also set the `--harmony` flag in node which will allow node to understand and utilize the generator function.

Comment: No, you don't need to transpile, you just need the `--harmony` flag. Of course you can transpile if you want.